# Print statement doesn’t work properly in iPad Playgrounds

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch, swift-playground

I’m trying to run a simple code that prints “foo” inside an asynchronous closure using iPad Playgrounds:

```swift
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
    print("foo")
}
```

yet it fails to show “foo” in a viewer(, a small resizable in-line block that appears).

Strangely,

```swift
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
    print("foo")
    let _ = 0
}
```

works.
What is happening? Is this a bug?

Also, is there a way to show a console with print outputs as in Xcode Playgrounds? I find the small ‘viewers’ a bit cumbersome to use.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I checked that Xcode Playgrounds shows () with the first code in a viewer, and shows "foo" properly with `let _ = 0` added. Nevertheless, I can see the output "foo" in both cases as I have a console output in the Xcode version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To your console question, cmd + shift + Y will bring up the console area, just as with any Xcode project

To your larger question of what is happening...

The closure that the `execute:` parameter of the asyncAfter function accepts is of type `() -> Void`. So the closure is returning [Void, which is typedef'd to an empty tuple ()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/void#). So the viewer is displaying the return value of the closure, an empty tuple.

Comment: @JayLee Ahh, apologies, I missed that you were in the iPad playground. [This link](https://ericasadun.com/2016/08/05/ios-playgrounds-where-is-my-print-output/) offers a method to allow you to embed the viewer. Not sure if there is a full on debug console though

Comment: Ok, I just saw the update. Now I see why Playground shows `()`. But then, what is the difference between the first and the later code? Why doesn't Playground shows a consistent value?

Comment: My gut feeling says it has to do with ARC. I suspect the closure is being retained when you define the variable. The aSync method you’re using defines its closure as `@autoescaping` which I believe means that it is released after the method is called. So when you define a variable within the closure that ups it’s reference count, causing it to be retained. Just a hypothesis though, haven’t tested it yet.